# Cannot access parameter in scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to pass parameters to a scripted pipeline.  From reading the docs, it should be simple, but I keep getting an error.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
node("spvlanautomation01.lab.dtcc.com") {
    parameters {
        string(name: 'VLAN', defaultValue: '', description: '')
    }
    stage("Find VLAN File") {
        echo "VLAN is ${params.VLAN}"
    }
}
```

I've tried

```
    echo "VLAN is ${VLAN}"
```

...and it didn't work either

Here is the error I get

```
Started by user anonymous
[Pipeline] node
Running on spvlanautomation01.lab.dtcc.com in /home/jenkins/workspace/build-vlan
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Find VLAN File)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: params for class: WorkflowScript
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getProperty(DefaultInvoker.java:26)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:6)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor675.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:164)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:324)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:78)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:236)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:224)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the parameters with Declarative Pipeline syntax. For Scripted Pipelines, the syntax is:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        string(name: 'VLAN', defaultValue: '', description: '')
    ])
])
node("spvlanautomation01.lab.dtcc.com") {
    stage("Find VLAN File") {
        echo "VLAN is ${params.VLAN}"
    }
}
```

> **Note**: The syntax `properties([ parameters([...]) ])` also works in Declarative Pipelines.

Comment: Do you have the correct plugins installed, specifically the Build With Parameters Plugin and Pipeline: Groovy Plugin 2.19 or higher? See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-40235.

Comment: Ok. I'll have a look at that